# Long HEX Value Split to 2bytes Hex values or 4bytes Hex Values and convert it to decimal (float) values Using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to split my long array to 2bytes (4 digit HEX) or 4bytes(8 digit HEX). If c value is 1, I want to get 2bytes (4 digit HEX) HEX array and if c value is 0, I want to get 4bytes(8 digit HEX) HEX array from a long HEX string.

After that, I want to convert while converting 2byte or 4byte to floating number( decimal number).

I have code for 4byte to a decimal value.

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = {&H43, &H62, &HD3, &HE}

If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
    Array.Reverse(bytes)

End If
Dim myFloat As Decimal = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
txt4.Text = myFloat
```

Please provide me the code for this function.

Example:

Long Hex value - `4362D30EFFC00000FFC00000FFFFFFFF`

If C is 1, split 4 digit HEX values.

```
4362
```

Then convert to decimal.

```
17250
```

Again split 4 digit HEX values.

```
D30E
```

Then convert to decimal

```
-11506
```

If c is 0, split 8 digit HEX values.

```
4362D30E
```

Then convert to decimal

```
226.824432
```

Please help with this. I don't not know much about VB.Net

Comment: If I use Convert.ToString(&HD30E, 16)Convert.ToString(&HD30E, 16) this gives same D30E value not -11506

Comment: For 2 bytes use [**`BitConverter.ToInt16()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint16), for 4 bytes use `ToSingle()`. If all those values are in a long byte array just reverse the entire thing and specify a start index in `ToSingle()` or `ToInt16()`. For instance, read two bytes from the end of the reversed array: `BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, bytes.Length - 2)`

Comment: _"this gives same D30E value not -11506"_ - That's because you specify it to use base 16 (hexadecimal): `Convert.ToString(xxx, 16)`. Just use `Convert.ToString(&HD30E)` or `&HD30E.ToString()`. In VB.NET typing `&HD30E` directly in code will compile it to `-11506`.

Comment: If I used Convert.ToString(&HD30E) it gives 54030.

Comment: According to https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/, I want -11506 value. That data type is int16 according that link

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's simply a conversion issue. When converting it from a string that problem doesn't occur: https://ideone.com/rUhGL9

Comment: Can't you give me a simple code for it? because I don't know much about VB.Net

Comment: The link was just to illustrate. We're getting a bit off-topic here... I explained what you needed in my first comment, and even gave you an example. You basically have done it already since you already know how to reverse an array and convert it to a number. Now you just gotta specify which part of the array to convert from.

Comment: You say you don't know very much about VB.NET, yet you've made great progress with both of your latest questions so far :). What you've been looking for is merely small tweaks.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for helping me. But that code I can not understand. I am looking for a simple code to convert 2 HEX byte to floating number.

Comment: I got following error in this line Dim Word As New WORD(DirectCast(&HD30E, UShort))   Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'UShort'.

Comment: Try `CType` instead of `DirectCast`, but again, that code was just for testing/illustration. It doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: You can't convert two bytes into a floating point number because floating point numbers are either 4 or 8 bytes long. As I said, convert the bytes to an Int16 (Short) like described in my first comment, then you'd have to convert that into a `Single` or `Double` using [**`CType`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function) if a floating point number is what you _really_ want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give this a shot as well, but do consider what I said on your newer question.

To read a certain amount of bytes and turn them into a number best is to use the [**`BitConverter`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and its `To***` methods.

This is how many bytes each numeric data type uses:

- `Double`: 8 bytes
- `Int16` / `UInt16` / `Short` / `UShort`: 2 bytes
- `Int32` / `UInt32` / `Integer` / `UInteger`: 4 bytes
- `Int64` / `UInt64` / `Long` / `ULong`: 8 bytes
- `Single`: 4 bytes

With this in mind, all you need is to decide on a data type based on the number of bytes you want to read, and then specify an index in your array where to start reading from.

Remember that if you reverse your array you have to start reading from the end of the array instead.

```
Dim StartIndex As Integer = 0
Dim EndIndex As Integer = bytes.Length - 1

'How many bytes to read: 2 or 4.
Dim BytesPerStep As Integer = If(C = 1, 2, 4)

'If the system uses little endianness we need to reverse the array and loop backwards.
If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
    'Reverse the array.
    Array.Reverse(bytes)

    'Swap start and end index.
    StartIndex = EndIndex
    EndIndex = 0

    'Negate BytesPerStep: Go backwards.
    BytesPerStep = -BytesPerStep
End If

'Iterate the array <BytesPerStep> bytes at a time.
For i = StartIndex To EndIndex Step BytesPerStep
    If C = 1 Then
        'Read two bytes = Short (Int16).
        ListBox1.Items.Add(BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, i))
    Else
        'Read four bytes = Single (Float)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, i))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much